# XML Xpath using PHP

Tags: php, xml, xpath

Here is my XML:

```
<div class="main">  
    <div class="workshoplist-main">
        <div class="toggler pointer">
            <i class="icon-chevron-down"></i> 
            <span id="rpt_0_lblSectionHeader_0">Wednesday, March 18, 2015 (10:00 AM - 11:00 AM)</span> 
            <p>Description of March info</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="workshoplist-main">
        <div class="toggler pointer">
            <i class="icon-chevron-down"></i> 
            <span id="rpt_0_lblSectionHeader_1">Thursday, April 16, 2015 (10:00 AM - 11:00 AM)</span> 
            <p>Description of April info</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="workshoplist-main">
        <div class="toggler pointer">
            <i class="icon-chevron-down"></i> 
            <span id="rpt_0_lblSectionHeader_2">Friday, March 19, 2015 (10:00 AM - 11:00 AM)</span> 
            <p>Description of March info</p>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

I want to look for the word `March` in the `span` element that contains `lblSectionHeader` in the `id`.

The return value I would like is:

```
 Wednesday, March 18, 2015 (10:00 AM - 11:00 AM)
 Friday, March 19, 2015 (10:00 AM - 11:00 AM)
```

My code is:

```
xpath("//div[contains(@class,'workshoplist-main') and //span[contains(@id,'lblSectionHeader')][text()='March']]");
```

I am getting no results. If anyone could help, that would be great.

Comment: That;s not a xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query works:

```
$html = <<<'EOF'
    ... Your HTML comes here ...
EOF;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$selector = new DOMXPath($doc);
$query = "//div[contains(@class,'workshoplist-main')]//span[contains(@id,'lblSectionHeader')][contains(text(), 'March')]";

foreach($selector->query($query) as $node) {
    // do something with that node
    var_dump($node);
}
```

You misused the `and` keyword in your query. If you want to select `<span>` tags below a `<div>` tag (regardless of the nesting level) then use `//div//span`, not `//div and //span`